# "not a type identifier" error in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I am new to Cython and I'm trying to get a test project working that calls a C function from Python:

**test.cpp**:

```
void testFn(int arr[]);

void testFn(int arr[])
{
    arr[0] = 1;
    arr[1] = 2;
}
```

**caller.pyx**:

```
cdef extern from "test.cpp":
    void testFn(int arr[])

cpdef myTest(*arr):
    testFn(arr)
```

**setup.caller.py**:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

sourcefiles = ['caller.pyx']
ext_modules = [Extension("caller", sourcefiles)]

setup(
    name = 'test app',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

But when I try to build the project I get an error:

```
$ python setup.caller.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
cythoning caller.pyx to caller.c

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef extern from "test.cpp":
    void testFn(int arr[])

cpdef myTest(*arr):
     ^
------------------------------------------------------------

caller.pyx:4:6: 'myTest' is not a type identifier
```

Comment: I guess you wanted to write `myTest(int *arr)`. But this also wont work because `int *arr` isn't a python object. You either should not declare this a python function (`cdef` instead of `cpdef`) or choose another signature.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I did not need "cpdef" or "cdef" for the second definition, the usual "def" did the trick:

```
def myTest(int[:] arr):
    testFn(&arr[0])
```